# Angular js and google maps

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I am a newbie in Angular js. So far I have managed to run some tutorial. But here is what I would really like to do. I have a service that gives me latitude and longitude. I would like to get these coordinates from the service and display them on the map. Can someone show me a quick example (could hard code the co-ordinates) on how this can be done? I am currently using Angular's service and controller modules.

Comment: Please give it a shot and then edit this question with code and concrete questions.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest ng-map.

The [google maps angularjs directive](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps) is called ng-map. This does not require any Javascript coding for simple functionality.

#### To Get Started

One. [Download](https://rawgithub.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/dist/ng-map.min.js) and include ng-map.js or ng-map.min.js

```
<script src="dist/ng-map.min.js"></script>`
```

Two. use `map` tag, and optionally, `control`, `marker`, and `shape` tags

```
<map zoom="11" center="[40.74, -74.18]">
  <marker position="[40.74, -74.18]" />
  <shape name="circle" radius="400" center="[40.74,-74.18]" radius="4000" />
  <control name="overviewMap" opened="true" />
</map>`
```

### Examples

- [Hello Map](https://rawgithub.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/examples/hello_map.html)
- [Markers](https://rawgithub.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/examples/marker.html)
- [Controls](https://rawgithub.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/examples/map_control.html)
- [Map Options](https://rawgithub.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/examples/map_options.html)
- [Shapes(Rectangle, Triangle, Image)](https://rawgithub.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/examples/shape.html)
- [Events](https://rawgithub.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/examples/events.html)

To use it in your app, simply include 'ngMap' as dependency to your app.

`var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMap']);`

Hope it helps

Comment: Hey, that is awesome. But what if these co-ordinates are coming from the service? How do I mark them on the map. What you have is a static example. Can you may be give some hints or explain how you would out dynamic co-ordinates there?